# what the ideal way to query dynamoDB from web app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I'm trying to query DynamoDB from my web application.

I successfully did that after using IAM and creating 3rd party Roles and make users log in my web app through Facebook or Google, my app obtained a token and created the AWS credentials.

Now, I want any user of my website, to be able to query one of my dynamoDB tables, which should be a public table, I tried doing that with Roles -mocking the previous way- but I always get an error"Missing credentials in config"?

How to avoid that? Is there a way to create AWS Credentials without a token from 3rd party and attach them to the IAM Role, or Did I have to create an IAM user instead with secret key, or is there any other better way to do that?

Comment: not sure why use IAM roles. Does your web application server have Fix IP, set in `security group` and let only that IP can access DynamoDB.

Comment: I'm trying to learn AWS, I don't have much experience with it. and I'm only running the website locally. could you please explain your idea further?

Comment: As far as I know, DynamoDB does not have "public" tables. Also, if you are querying DynamoDB directly from a webapp, the users will have access to whatever credentials you served as part of the site.

Comment: I was able to do that successfully, after creating an IAM User with readOnly permessions to my DynamoDB and hard code associated accessKey and sercreteAccessKey in my web app. By reading about AWS IAM, I understood that user is one user or one entity, e.g:me or you, and the relation is one-to-one, but can I assume that user means web_user, in this case this will be relation one-to-many or anyone using my website will use these same credentials, and if I assumed that, would that make any problems? and Does it contradict any IAM best practices?

Comment: In the case you are describing, it would be the *web_user* scenario.You need to be careful about what permissions and credentials you would be exposing to users of your webapp. Your IAM user should be **very** limited in scope to whatever permissions it has, because a malicious user can take those credentials and abuse any privileges you grant them. There are some [policy keys that are specific to DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/UsingIAMWithDDB.html#IAMPolicyKeys) that could be used to further restrict access.

Comment: I have just done exactly this, much of the sample code is in: [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327179/iam-gives-access-to-one-dynamodb-method-but-not-another-using-javascript-to-aws/34341982#34341982).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like Amazon Cognito is what you need here. If you are looking for an example web application, a recent blog post was published on a sample application using Amazon Cognito to authenticate users to access a DynamoDB table. http://www.infoq.com/articles/mars-rover-application-DynamoDB

Specifically, you may find the section "Application authenticates user via Amazon Cognito" useful.

Hopefully that helps! Good luck!